# I need help improving my pseudocode for this assignment

Tags: logic, branch, pseudocode

The assignment says:

> Write a pseudocode for the logic of a  program that accepts multiple numbers up to 5 from a user and displays one of the following messages:- The largest number is  __.  The smallest number is __

We are working on branches and this is a branches assignment, so I am not sure on if I should use other things like arrays which I have seen suggested before. This is what I have so far. It just seems wrong to me like there is something I am missing and what I have seems so jumbled and too long and could be shortened up. I know you guys rightfully have an issue when people come here and blatantly expect you to do their homework for them. I am really trying hard to figure it out myself or at least attempt it myself before I ask for help on it.

Input a number from user, save as `numOne`

Input a second number from user, save as `numTwo`

Input a third number from user, save as `numThree`

Input a fourth number from user, save as `numFour`

Input a fifth number from user, save as `numFive`

```
If **numOne** > **numTwo** && **numOne** > **numThree** && **numOne** > **numFour** && **numOne** > **numFive**

Print “The largest number is ” + **numOne** 

Else If **numTwo** > **numOne** && *numTwo* > **numThree** && **numTwo** > **numFour** && **numTwo** > **numFive**

Print “The largest number is “ + **numTwo**

Else If **numThree** > **numOne** && **numThree** > **numTwo** && **numThree** > **numFour** && **numThree** > **numFive**
Print “The largest number is “ + **numThree**

Else If **numFour** > **numOne** && **numFour** > **numTwo** && **numFour** > **numThree** && **numFour** > **numFive**

Print “The largest number is “ + **numFour**

Else If **numFive** > **numOne** && **numFive** > **numTwo** && **numFive** > **numThree** && **numFive** > **numFour**

Print “The largest number is “ + **numFive**

If **numOne** < **numTwo** && **numOne** < **numThree** && **numOne** < **numFour** && **numOne** < **numFive**

Print “The smallest number is ” + **numOne** 

Else If **numTwo** < **numOne** && **numTwo** **< numThree** && **numTwo** < **numFour** && **numTwo** < **numFive**

Print “The smallest number is “ + **numTwo**

Else If **numThree** < **numOne** && **numThree** < **numTwo** && **numThree** < **numFour** && **numThree** < **numFive**

Print “The smallest number is “ + **numThree**

Else If **numFour** < **numOne** && **numFour** < **numTwo** && **numFour** < **numThree** && **numFour** < **numFive**

Print “The smallest number is “ + **numFour**

Else If **numFive** < **numOne** && **numFive** < **numTwo** && **numFive** < **numThree** && **numFive** < **numFour**

Print “The smallest number is “ + **numFive**
```

Comment: If I have to write pseudocode I always give it to a computer. Because computers can check whether it works better than I can. So what I end up doing is writing pseudocode, translating it to JavaScript or something similar, correct some small mistakes, then translate it back to pseudocode.

Comment: @helpthisnewbie540 - Are you sure that _multiple numbers up to 5_ means (up to) five numbers and not multiple (unspecified how many) numbers with a maximum value of 5?